# how to replace property values in a dynamic JSON?

Tags: c#, jsonresponse

I'm reading my json file from and trying to replace the property values. JSON file is below.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "summaryValue",
    "project": {
      "key": "projectValue"
    },
    "priority": {
      "name": "priorityValue"
    },

    "Requestor": {
      "name": "RequestorValue"
    },
    
    "issue": {
      "name": "issueValue"
    },
    "labels": "LabelValue",
    "customfield_xyz": "customfield_xyzValue"
  }
}
```

How can I replace the value for each item inside the fields property ?
for ex:

```
{"fields": {
    "summary": "NewsummaryValue",
    "project": {
      "key": "NewprojectValue"
    },
    "priority": {
      "name": "NewpriorityValue"
    }
}
}
```

Below is the code to parse my json file,

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath);
                var jsondata = r.ReadToEnd();
                var jobj = JObject.Parse(jsondata);
 foreach (var item in jobj.Properties())
                {
                    \\replace code
                }
```

Comment: Do you really want to replace in a loop? Wouldn't it be easier to replace the properties you want just by accessing them directly? like `jobj["fields"]["project"]["key"].Value = "Newprojectvalue";`? The [NewtonSoft JSON.NET documentation has plenty of sample code](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) that is quite illustrative.

Comment: You mean `jobj["fields"] = JToken.FromObject(new { summary = "NewsummaryValue",
    project = new {
      key = "NewprojectValue"
    },
    priority = new {
      name = "NewpriorityValue"
    }});`? Or are you trying to generically merge arbitrary objects?

Comment: A tip: Use `dynamic` only if you know how to avoid using it exactly for this job. Otherwise you'll may meet more issues than it could be such as this one. Also Json+dynamic consume ~twice more memory and works slower because the values are wrapped with JTokens which is a kind of redundancy if you have a `class` of proper data model.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what you want. But I changed the json information in the code snippet as you wanted.

```
dynamic dataCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);
          
string summary = dataCollection["fields"]["summary"];
string project = dataCollection["fields"]["project"]["key"];
string priority = dataCollection["fields"]["priority"]["name"];

dynamic json = new JObject();
json.summary = summary;
json.project = project;
json.priority = priority;

dynamic jsonRoot = new JObject();
jsonRoot.fields = json;

Console.WriteLine(jsonRoot.ToString());
```

output:

[image]